# hammer js mousedown or tap down?

Tags: hammer.js

I want to create slider drag functionality which should initiate on mousedown of the handle. Right now, I don't see any event in hammer js that would fire once the element is touched. Is there something built in or do I use plain javascript to detect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [version `1.1`](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/wiki) had inbuilt [`touch` event](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started#gesture-events).

However, after the rewrite [newer version](http://hammerjs.github.io/) seems to be [missing any such event](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js#events-1), But you can create such a custom event as shown [here](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js#more-control), by modifying the [tap](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js#hammertapoptions) gestures options.

Something like

```
var myOptions = { };
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement, myOptions);
mc.add(new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'touch', taps: 1, interval:15, time:10 }));
mc.on("touch", handleTaps);
```

Or you can use the native `touchstart` event to detect a touch. However not that you don't have much control over this and will be triggered every time a touch occurs, for eg, like when the user is trying to scroll.